# Apache is running, but I don't get any sign from my web browser

Tags: apache, virtualhost, host

I am on MacOsX 10.9.3 and My apache is running:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
```

Apache is running and inside my /etc/hosts I have:

```
127.0.0.1 qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com
```

I can ping qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com but I cannot see from my browser

```
http://qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com/
```

And this is my virtualhost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/root
    ServerName qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com
    ServerAlias qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and curl did not get anything

```
$ curl http://qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com
curl: (7) Failed connect to qwertyuiopoiuytrewq.mnbvcxzxcvbnm.com:80; Connection refused
```

What's wrong? Maybe the port that Apache is listening? How can I check which port is used by my apache service?

```
$ lsof -i | grep apache
```

responds nothing ... I've tried with a command suggested by a colleague

```
$ lsof -i :80
```

But ...

```
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    13069 simonegentili   84u  IPv4 0xec5b6b421454cd89      0t0  TCP     192.168.11.46:52061->fa-in-f95.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    13069 simonegentili  105u  IPv4 0xec5b6b421304ed89      0t0  TCP 192.168.11.46:52100->mil02s05-in-f13.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    13069 simonegentili  125u  IPv4 0xec5b6b42172fe5a1      0t0  TCP 192.168.11.46:51372->mil01s16-in-f1.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    13069 simonegentili  138u  IPv4 0xec5b6b42145a7d89      0t0  TCP 192.168.11.46:52070->edge-star-shv-07-fra3.facebook.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've tried to check which port is apache listening:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf | grep Listen
```

Apache should respond to 80 port.

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

---

And for example, I dont understand this answer:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
$ ps aux | grep httpd
simonegentili   26677   0.0  0.0  2444976    416 s001  U+    6:13PM   0:00.00 grep httpd
```

Comment: Are there any httpd processes actually running? It seems like your apachectl has some vendor customization to use some alternate service facility (the upstream tools do not report org.apache.httpd:"

Comment: The bottom of the error log is also usually pretty helpful.

Comment: Updated my answer. I "think" that apache is on, but I am not sure. Could you read the bottom of my question to understand why.

Comment: Seems like your problem is with the service control on your system, since only your "grep" command itself is in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this can happen when you've broken httpd.conf. Instead of reporting the normal apache config parsing error with line numbers and all that, the service manager misleads you.

See:

http://neverblog.net/solving-org-apache-httpd-already-loaded-error-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

> Checking running processes, I noticed that apache wasn’t actually
>   running, which seemed a bit strange. Luckily, apachectl offers a
>   helpful command for checking your config syntax, apachectl configtest.
>   Sure enough, it turned out I’d modified the httpd.conf a couple of
>   weeks ago, but never rebooted Apache. Commenting out the offending
>   line and starting Apache fixed the problem and I’m back up and
>   running.

So then at least you just have to debug a normal httpd.conf error rather than this mystery.

Comment: Thank you very much! "apachectl configtest" tells me where configuration was wrong. Fixed. But, ... why any errors shows me this stuff? I mean, ... any apache errors!! Mystery.

Answer (score 2):

A ping is testing that the host is reachable over the network, and is typically handled by your kernel instead of any software running on top. Pinging has verified that the host is there, that has nothing to do with Apache listening on the port.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29)

Answer (score 1):

You have to start apache service using this command `/etc/init.d/apache2` start, 127.0.0.1 is a just loopback network interface.

Comment: I've modified the question. All browsers responds nothing. When apache is running and when is not.